# Testing for Exceptions in phpunit testing

Tags: phpunit

At the beginning of the function I am trying to test, there is a check to see that the required inputs are set.  If they are not an exception is thrown:

```
    public function save(array $input) {
        if (!isset($input['var1']) || !isset($input['var2'])) {
            throw new BadRequestException('Invalid parameters for ' . $this->class . ':save');
        } .........rest of function
```

Do I need to separate this out into another function to test the exception?  I know I want to test this if var1 is set and var2 is not set, as well as if var2 is set and var1 is not set.  Do I test in the testSave function, or should I separate it out into another testing function?  If I do test in the same function, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert that a specific exception is thrown using the `@expectedException` annotation.

#### Example:

```
/**
 * @test
 * @dataProvider dataInvalidInput
 * @expectedException BadRequestException
 */
public function saveShouldThrowException($invalidInput)
{
    $this->subject->save($invalidInput);
}
public static function dataInvalidInput()
{
    return array(
        'var1_missing' => array('var2' => 1),
        'var2_missing' => array('var1' => 1),
        'both_missing' => array('var3' => 1),
    );
}
```

You can also assert code and message of the exception with `@expectedExceptionCode` and `@expectedExceptionMessage`.

Read more in the manual: [Testing Exceptions](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions)

Comment: Doesn't this just test the exception?  Will the save function continue to test?

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get what you're saying.  Test the save function with correct inputs, and then test that the exception will be thrown this way.  Thank you